# Excel: AND formula when using multiple datasets of different lengths

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two datasets: both have an `id` column and a `date` column.

- Dataset A can have multiple `date` entries (rows) per `id` - i.e., it is a long dataset
- Dataset B only has one `date` entry per `id`

The two datasets are in a single spreadsheet:

- Columns A and B are the `id` and `date` for dataset A
- Columns E and F are the `id` and `date` for dataset B

I am trying to use the `=AND` formula in Excel to determine which rows in Dataset A match exactly to their respective row in Dataset B.

**Example**

Here is a toy example with the desired results in Column C.

[image: Here is a toy example with the desired results in Column C]

**How should this be coded?**

I assumed that the following formula in column C (e.g., `C2=AND(A2=E:E,B2=F:F)` would return `TRUE` when the exact match occurs; however, the formula returns `FALSE` in all cells.

Comment: You never showed us sample data, but I'm guessing that the A dataset's dates are in some sort of CSV format.  Don't do that; normalize your data and get each date onto a separate row.  Even still, answering your question might be difficult, but possible.

Comment: Ah - I was just editing this now. I forgot to include a toy dataset...

Comment: countifs should be suffiecient for this.

Comment: @Jeeped - do you mean something like C2=COUNTIFS(A2,E:E,B2,F:F)? That still returns '0' in every cell.

Comment: @Jeeped - my mistake. I have the formula the wrong way around. C2=COUNTIFS(E:E,A2,F:F,B2) provides '1' in the correct cells.

Comment: `=AND(COUNTIFS(E:E,A2,F:F,B2))` for TRUE/FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

So my method is pretty lengthy but here's the code
I put this under C2

> =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,F:F,1,FALSE)), "FALSE", "TRUE")

So basically VLookup looks at B2 and checks if its in the F column.

If it isn't it returns N/A, if it is, it returns the date value.
So if the value is N/A, it will return "FALSE", which in C2 it does return.

It should return "TRUE" for the corresponding true values.
The third parameter is 1 by default since F:F has only 1 column.

There's probably more elegant solutions but I hope that helps!